# Regarding spatial relationships, what is the Dimensionally Extended 9 Intersection Model (DE-9IM)?

Tags: relates, gis-principle, de-9im

In plain English what is the [Dimensionally Extended nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM)?

What is the meaning of each row/column in the matrix?

How can I use that information to build a relation matrix?

Comment: The Clementini papers referenced by Wikipedia are written  in English (with math subtitles). I doubt a *simple* explanation of Clementini spatial calculus exists. Can you clarify what you're looking to accomplish?  There's a lot of permutations for a generic answer.

Comment: The duplicate does not specifically ask about the  DE-9IM. It is being mention to one of the answers, without great detail as well. Voting to remove the duplicate flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to understand the Dimensionally Extended nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM) or Clementini Matrice, read Christian Stobl [Dimensionally Extended Nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM)(pdf)](http://giswiki.hsr.ch/images/3/3d/9dem_springer.pdf). You can also read the explications in [PostGIS: 4.3.6. Dimensionally Extended 9 Intersection Model (DE-9IM)](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#DE-9IM)

The method allows to create spatial filters to find relationships impossible to obtain  by traditional methods.

If you want to learn it, use the [JTS Topology Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/).

[image]

The Clementini resulting matrice:

[image]

Shows/means

- that the intersection of the interior of the 2 polygons (Int,Int) is a polygon (dimension 2)

[image]

- that the intersection of the interior of a Polygon with the exterior of the other (Int, Ext and Ext,Int) is a polygon (dimension 2)

[image]

- that the intersection of the boundary of one polygon with the interior of the other (Int,Bdy and Bdy,Int) is a polyline (dimension 1)

[image]

- that the intersection of the two polygons boundary (Bdy,Bdy)  is a point (dimension 0)

[image]

- if there is no intersection, the predicate in the matrix is F

Typically, you use a pattern to find the result: two lines that intersect on a line would be: '1*1***1**', for example

You can use this method in:

- PostGIS, and other spatial databases (look at [PostGIS: 4.3.6. Dimensionally Extended 9 Intersection Model (DE-9IM)](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#DE-9IM) for example)

> A second [theoretical] example may be that of a GIS analyst trying to locate all wharfs or docks that intersect a lake's boundary on a line and where only one end of the wharf is up on shore. In other words, where a wharf is within, but not completely within a lake, intersecting the boundary of a lake on a line, and where the wharf's endpoints are both completely within and on the boundary of the lake. The analyst may need to use a combination of spatial predicates to isolate the sought after features:

[image]

The pattern is `102101FF2`

```
 #Identify wharfs partly on a lake's shoreline  
 SELECT a.lake_id, b.wharf_id  
 FROM lakes a, wharfs b  
 WHERE a.geom && b.geom  
 AND ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom, '102101FF2');
```

- ArcGIS ([Relational functions for ST_Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006z0000001z000000))
- The Python modules [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) (look at [Python: module Shapely , geometry, spatial predicates, spatial analysis,  Clementini matrices (DE-9IM), shapefiles processing and representation with matplotlib (in French)](http://www.portailsig.org/content/python-le-module-shapely-geometries-predicats-spatiaux-analyse-spatiale-matrices-de-clementi)) and [de9im](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/de9im/0.1)

There are many examples of patterns/Clementini Matrix in [Dimensionally Extended Nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM)(pdf)](http://giswiki.hsr.ch/images/3/3d/9dem_springer.pdf)

"